# Typescript complains on promise.then

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, promise, es6-promise

Consider following code:

```
Promise.resolve('hello')
    .then(a => console.log(a))
    .catch(() => console.log("error"))
    .then(() => console.log("ok"));
```

This gets me a very annoying error:

> supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:
>   expected 0 parameter(s) but was called with 1 parameter(s)

Note that I only get this for the first `.then(...)`, the catch and the second then are apparently no problem.

Just for the record; the code works and outputs

```
hello
ok
```

Maybe I should also mention that it actually compiles. I see the error in Visual Studio 2017. When I go to the definition of *then* it opens *lib.es6.d.ts*. Compilation happens with webpack 4 that uses TypeScript 2.8.3. In Visual Sudio I have installed TypeScript 2.8.1 (Can't find 2.8.3)

If someone could explain to me why this happens. And even better, how to get rid of it; that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What version of TypeScript are you using? Are you sure this error message is from TypeScript and not from a linter for example?

Comment: This cannot be replicated and should work as expected, https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=Promise.resolve(%27hello%27)%0D%0A%20%20.then(a%20%3D%3E%20console.log(a))%0D%0A%20%20.catch(()%20%3D%3E%20console.log(%22error%22))%0D%0A%20%20.then(()%20%3D%3E%20console.log(%22ok%22))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20 . You don't get this error by using `tsc` directly outside VS, do you?

Comment: @str: as far as I know there are no linters configured, type script version is 2.8.3

Comment: @estus: No indeed it seems to be a VS problem. When I run tsc I get 3 errors in the file _node_modules/@types/react-hot-loader/index.d.ts_ but not the error I see in VS.

Comment: Maybe try wrapping function body in curly braces? ie `then(a => { console.log(a) } )`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I tried, but it does not help either.

Comment: @popStar: I don't think it is the same. This article would explain the problem if I would do `.then(() => console.log(arguments[0]))` but I don't use the `arguments` variable. Also converting it to `.then(function(a) { console.log(a); })` does not help.

Comment: Mysterious. `.then(console.log)` or `.then(consol.log.bind(console))`are also a possibilities.

Comment: Are you using Resharper by chance?

Comment: @JBC yes I am, would that be a problem?

Comment: I'd try suspending Resharper and see if the "error" goes away (Options > Resharper > Suspend Now).  I commonly deal with Resharper reporting false errors in TypeScript.

Comment: Also, are you using a polyfill for the promise?  There might be issues with the d.ts for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and as the comment by @JBC alluded, it's caused by ReSharper. In my case I was running a rather old version (2017.1.1) so updating to the latest (or disabling it altogether) fixed it.